# How to make an efficient and fast long query for Neo4J: optimize Cypher or improve the Javascript / Node.Js constructor?

Tags: javascript, node.js, neo4j, cypher

I have a task for a Node.Js app that converts text into network (the words are the nodes and their co-occurrences — of several weights — are the connections in the network graph), where I need to save all the data into the Neo4J database.

As you can imagine, while it works for short statements, as soon as they get longer, like, for example, 5000 words where the vocabulary is about 500 unique words, I need to save a lot of nodes and a lot of connections into the database.

At the moment, I have a request of this kind:

```
MATCH (u:User {uid: "15229100-b20e-11e3-80d3-6150cb20a1b9"}) 
MERGE (c_0:Context {name:"st",by:u.uid,uid:"d0342000-1c4c-11e9-b9f6-e1addb3b0fa7"}) 
ON CREATE SET c_0.timestamp="15479451847980000" MERGE (c_0)-[:BY{timestamp:"15479451847980000"}]->(u) 
CREATE (s:Statement {name:"#apple #orange #fruit", text:"apples and oranges are fruits", uid:"d0390200-1c4c-11e9-b9f6-e1addb3b0fa7", timestamp:"15479451847980000"}) 
CREATE (s)-[:BY {context:c_0.uid,timestamp:s.timestamp}]->(u) 
CREATE (s)-[:IN {user:u.id,timestamp:s.timestamp}]->(c_0) 
MERGE (cc_0:Concept {name:"apple"}) 
ON CREATE SET cc_0.uid="d0390201-1c4c-11e9-b9f6-e1addb3b0fa7" 
MERGE (cc_1:Concept {name:"orange"}) 
ON CREATE SET cc_1.uid="d0390204-1c4c-11e9-b9f6-e1addb3b0fa7" 
MERGE (cc_2:Concept {name:"fruit"}) 
ON CREATE SET cc_2.uid="d0390207-1c4c-11e9-b9f6-e1addb3b0fa7" 
CREATE (cc_0)-[:BY {context:c_0.uid,timestamp:s.timestamp,statement:s.uid}]->(u) 
CREATE (cc_0)-[:OF {context:c_0.uid,user:u.uid,timestamp:s.timestamp}]->(s)  
CREATE (cc_0)-[:AT {user:u.uid,timestamp:s.timestamp,context:c_0.uid,statement:s.uid}]->(c_0) 
CREATE (cc_0)-[:TO {context:c_0.uid,statement:s.uid,user:u.uid,timestamp:"15479451847980000",uid:"d0390205-1c4c-11e9-b9f6-e1addb3b0fa7",gapscan:"2",weight:"3"}]->(cc_1) 
CREATE (cc_1)-[:BY {context:c_0.uid,timestamp:"15479451847980000",statement:s.uid}]->(u) CREATE (cc_1)-[:OF {context:c_0.uid,user:u.uid,timestamp:"15479451847980000"}]->(s) 
CREATE (cc_1)-[:AT {user:u.uid,timestamp:"15479451847980000",context:c_0.uid,statement:s.uid}]->(c_0) 
CREATE (cc_1)-[:TO {context:c_0.uid,statement:s.uid,user:u.uid,timestamp:"15479451847980002",uid:"d0390208-1c4c-11e9-b9f6-e1addb3b0fa7",gapscan:"2",weight:"3"}]->(cc_2) 
CREATE (cc_0)-[:TO {context:c_0.uid,statement:s.uid,user:u.uid,timestamp:"15479451847980002",uid:"d039020a-1c4c-11e9-b9f6-e1addb3b0fa7",gapscan:"4",weight:"2"}]->(cc_2) 
CREATE (cc_2)-[:BY {context:c_0.uid,timestamp:"15479451847980002",statement:s.uid}]->(u) 
CREATE (cc_2)-[:OF {context:c_0.uid,user:u.uid,timestamp:"15479451847980002"}]->(s) 
CREATE (cc_2)-[:AT {user:u.uid,timestamp:"15479451847980002",context:c_0.uid,statement:s.uid}]->(c_0)  
RETURN s.uid;
```

For this paragraph of text:

```
apples and oranges are fruits
```

As you can see it turns out to be much longer than necessary.

At the moment for longer texts I simply split the Cypher request into smaller chunks and feed them to the DB in a transaction.

However, this still is quite slow — about a second for each KB of text.

My query is being built in Javascript / Node.Js here: https://github.com/noduslabs/infranodus/blob/master/lib/db/neo4j.js#L116

The basic logic is:

If there's a sentence like `apples and oranges are fruits`

1. I need to create a node for each, link them to the `user` who created them as well as to the `statement` itself and to the `graph` (a graph can have several statements).
2. Then I need to create connections between these words with different weights:

   [apples - oranges]

   [oranges - fruits]

   [apples - fruits]

...

What would be an efficient way to do this for a sequence of say, 300 words?

I know I could use `FOREACH` cycles and `params` as well as `apoc` to generate UIDs, but would it really make the query more efficient comparing to building it using JavaScript? I don't quite understand how to do this on my set and whether it would help deal with the problem of it being too heavy for 300+ word sequences.

Would these practices help and how could I implement them into this Cypher query?

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is more the huge statements, which have to be parsed, compiled and planned.

It's better to use batches of **parameters** as inputs and let cypher do the iteration,
see

https://medium.com/neo4j/5-tips-tricks-for-fast-batched-updates-of-graph-structures-with-neo4j-and-cypher-73c7f693c8cc

What do you need all the UUID's for?

Do you have the indexes and constraints set for your MERGE operations?

Comment: Hey! The UUIDs are needed as I often use them to search / parse the graph in the frontend. I have indexes set for all but regarding the constraints — the reason to implement them is only data integrity or it also improves the speed? Can I set constraints on edges?

Comment: And when you say "statements" you mean my Cypher statements or the actual nodes of type :Statement in my query? do you suggest I instead pass all the parameters as params to the query? is that making things faster?

Comment: I meant your Cypher statements. Yes parameters will make it faster as the parser/compiler can reuse query plans and don't have to reparse/compile every time.